# "/checkout/" after installed theme on the magento_2.5.5

Tags: php, magento2

Help, pls.:
when I installed a test theme for Magento_2.2.5 - the "magento-theme.com/checkout/" disappeared.
need - http://prntscr.com/kcq0g0,
but now like this - http://prntscr.com/kcq1pk   -   is empty :(

I do not understand how I can display the required fields here like - http://prntscr.com/kcq0g0

Comment: Error log? This stinks as server internal error (500)

Comment: You question is not specific enough

Comment: @Rickert , what do y mean? I do not have any problems in the inspector. I have a clean field (just have the only logo in the header), hen after what it happens to me: when I ckicked prntscr.com/kcrm3x - I go streight up and prntscr.com/kcrnvi - after click "Proceed to Checkout" It leads me to the page prntscr.com/kcrotx

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some debugging here .

So for that take a look inside root pub/errors folder,

Just copy local.xml.sample to local.xml

Also you can enable display_errors from app/bootstrap.php file.

Now the final statement displays as ini_set('display_errors', 1);

If you see some errors after following above steps then share with us here.

I hope it helps.

Comment: There are no errors in the console.
I do not understand - "Just copy local.xml.sample to local.xml" and "Now the final statement displays as ini_set('display_errors', 1);".
"Also you can enable display_errors from app/bootstrap.php file" - this is I am did

Comment: "Just copy local.xml.sample to local.xml" and "Now the final statement displays as ini_set('display_errors', 1);".

These are the ways to find the bugs.If you are non-tech then ask someone to help you out.

Comment: @Владислав .. Share your site access in private message so I can better take a look

Comment: when I ckicked http://prntscr.com/kcrm3x - I go streight up and http://prntscr.com/kcrnvi   -   after click "Proceed to Checkout" It leads me to the page http://prntscr.com/kcrotx

Comment: I can debug the issue man.I cannot guess what is going wrong in the code.

Comment: can give your skype?

Comment: I send you mail. Pls., check and give me feedback

Comment: replied few min ago.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an 500 internal server error only. May be you have not configured your theme properly.
To check the exact error open app/bootstrap.php an around at line no. 11 you will get this line: 
"#ini_set('display_errors', 1);"

replace it with

"ini_set('display_errors', 1);"

And reload your checkout page. You will get exact error on page.

Answer (score 0):

I have bad code in the generated/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template —- Interceptor.php (280 row).
Changed like this:
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{

```
if (!isset($this->area)) {
    $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
}
return $this;
```

}